# Использование USB-OTG в режиме MSC-HOST

Tags: c, usb, stm32, прерывания

Пытаюсь запустить USB OTG в режиме MSC Host. Немного адаптировал [данный проект](http://mikrocontroller.bplaced.net/wordpress/?page_id=383) под МК **STM32F105** и исправил некоторые ошибки. Выложил основную часть исправленного проекта [здесь](https://github.com/antonkiryukhin/USB-OTG-MSC-HOST). Но сейчас выполнение программы останавливается в бесконечном цикле в файле **stm32_ub_usb_msc_host.c**:

```
USB_MSC_HOST_STATUS_t UB_USB_MSC_HOST_Do(void)
{
  if(USB_MSC_HOST_STATUS!=USB_MSC_DEV_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
    // когда флешка USB не поддерживается,
    // функция не будет вызываться
    USBH_Process(&USB_OTG_Core, &USB_Host);
  }
  return(USB_MSC_HOST_STATUS);
}
```

В функции USBH_Process() программа ожидает прерывание по вектору **OTG_FS_IRQHandler**. Чтобы затем перевести состояние переменной **USB_MSC_HOST_STATUS** в **USB_MSC_DEV_CONNECTED**. Но прерывания не происходит. Также хотелось бы уточнить, что прерывание ожидается в case HOST_IDLE:

```
void USBH_Process(USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev , USBH_HOST *phost)
{
  volatile USBH_Status status = USBH_FAIL;
     switch (phost->gState)
  {
  case HOST_ISSUE_CORE_RESET :
    if ( HCD_ResetPort(pdev) == 0)
    {
      phost->gState = HOST_IDLE;
    }
    break; 
  case HOST_IDLE :   
    if (HCD_IsDeviceConnected(pdev)) 
    {
      /* Wait for USB Connect Interrupt void USBH_ISR_Connected(void) */    
      USBH_DeAllocate_AllChannel(pdev);
      phost->gState = HOST_DEV_ATTACHED;
    }
    break;
 ...
```

В случае если прерывание **OTG_FS_IRQHandler** произойдет, то **host.ConnSts** присвоится 1. И тогда программа войдет в case **HOST_DEV_ATTACHED**. Но пока этого нет. Прерывание проинициализировано:

```
void USB_OTG_BSP_EnableInterrupt(USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev)
{

  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  /* Enable USB Interrupt */
  NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_1);

  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = OTG_FS_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
}
```

Шина USB затактирована:

```
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USB, ENABLE);
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_OTG_FS, ENABLE);
```

В чем может быть причина отсутствия перехода в прерывание?

Comment: Проблема разрешилась. Дело было в схеме подключения. DM и DP были подтянуты к питанию. Убрал эти подтяжки и флешка законнектилась, теперь вот надо справиться с монтированием/размонтированием и записью файла.